# Event in v-data-table's template fires for every item?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<v-data-table :items="eventData" item-key="myID" ...>
  ...
  <template v-slot:item="{ item, index }">
    ...
    <v-checkbox v-model="item.isSelected" :update:modelValue="selectIndividual(index, item)"></v-checkbox>
    ...
  </template>
</v-data-table>

// in my component code-behind:
selectIndividual(index, item) {
  console.log(index, item);
},
```

I have the above. A v-data-table with a template that slots in for the item and inside that template I have a checkbox. Every row in the table will have this checkbox. The checkbox is mixed in with other components so I can't use the checkbox provided by v-data-table's `show-select` functionality.

This gets me most of the way to where I want to be. It looks good and the function runs on model change. However, when I click on ANY row in the v-data-table I see a console output for EVERY row on the visible page. I would like for the event of the singular row I clicked to fire and none of the others. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Syntax error.  update:modelValue is an event, so should be `@update:modelValue` not `:update:modelValue`

Comment: @yoduh, after making that change the event doesn't fire at all. There's also no error in the console. Clicking the checkbox toggles the checkbox state and nothing else.

Comment: There's something else not right.  Please provide minimal, reproducible example.  [My attempt here works](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkDFPwzAQhf/KyUtBapKhLERpBQxIzEgsTQfXuYKFY0exHVVE+e9c3JgoDAip0yV337vnd/ue2VZkj02Tdh5ZzgqHdaO4w12pAYouqbjjieNHhZBLGtptyUItWUAIihLoEquMCxhRPYwfa5C6wjMMP3xYKz5QfB7NObaAxLWpUE3rU2lfUaFwWJVshh58Qw/CPKBvXHkk3gbwRVeyk5Xn6iY4kjHtuZ3VuyKbfePbs2VeIubA1FrM6deKVjYOLDrfBIUw2rrgZGEL+8vWPlpqXmMOq2djVuvYm4PlcOLK4jQZpvpb/MTba8Rf/xUfxoAAJ6+Fk0ZTxj+uGo3G+EZhqsz78uo0HcbzXQ5Gp2LDmm3STXrPxnpH9fAN2CPIxA==)

Comment: Your example is configured for Vue 3, this is a Vue 2 question.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice the tag.  I only thought it was Vue 3 because `update:modelValue` is Vue 3/Vuetify 3 v-model syntax.  For Vue 2 you just want to instead use the `@change` event as noted in the [Vuetify 2 API](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#events)

Comment: That did the trick! It's frustrating trying to reconcile so many different versions of vue, vuetify, v-data-table's docs, and v-checkbox's docs when you're new to vue as a whole.

Comment: Awesome.  With the confusion cleared up I've posted an official answer response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the v-checkbox to use `@change` event which is the correct event for Vuetify 2 v-checkbox

```html
<v-checkbox v-model="item.isSelected" @change="selectIndividual(index, item)"></v-checkbox>
```